# How to solve @Sendable warnings inside completion block

Tags: swift, swift5.7

I enabled Strict Swift Concurrency Check and get some warnings. I would love to discuss and understand them. This is my code.

```
class DownloadImageAsyncImageLoader {
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/200")!
    
    func handleResponse(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?) -> UIImage? {
        guard let data = data,
        let image = UIImage(data: data),
        let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
              response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return image
    }
    
    func downloadWithEscaping(completion: @escaping (UIImage?, Error?) -> Void) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
            guard let image = self?.handleResponse(data: data, response: response) else {
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            
            completion(image, nil)
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

I got two warnings inside URLSession data task callback.

> 1. Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'DownloadImageAsyncImageLoader?' in a `@Sendable` closure.

This class has no data at all. I can make it final and conform to Sendable explicitly. Then this warning goes away. If this class cannot be final, what should we do?

> 2. Capture of 'completion' with non-sendable type '(UIImage?, (any Error)?) -> Void' in a `@Sendable` closure

I have no idea how to address this one.

Comment: How about switching to Swift Concurrency and making your methods `async throws`?

Comment: Strict concurrency means that your entire codebase has been converted to the new Concurrency completion handlers should be replaced by newer versions and/or converted.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest that you write this using Swift Concurrency, instead of using completion handlers. It would look something like this:

```
func downloadWithEscaping() async throws -> UIImage {
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
    
    guard let image = handleResponse(data: data, response: response) else {
        throw Errors.invalidImage
    }
    
    return image
}

enum Errors: Error {
    case invalidImage
}
```

---

As for the second error, it is saying that your completion handler is not `@Sendable`. You can fix the error by just marking it as `@Sendable`,

```
func downloadWithEscaping(completion: @escaping @Sendable (UIImage?, Error?) -> Void)
```

but of course this puts certain restrictions on what you can do in the completion handler (the same restrictions as what you can do in the completion handler of `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)`), so you might get more errors depending on how you use this method.

For the first error, if your class cannot be `final`, that means subclasses can add whatever properties they like in a non-sendable way, so capturing `self` is inherently unsafe.

That said, `handleResponse` doesn't use any instance properties. It might as well be a `static func` (or `class func` if you allow subclasses to override it). Then you can call it with `Self.handleResponse(...)` instead of `self.handleResponse(...)`.